# Is there any Booking/Reservation system for Craft 3?

Tags: plugins

I couldn't find any booking/reservation system for Craft. Is there any? I found questions from 2014, so things could change.

Maybe there is community-approved booking/reservation service that is commonly used with Craft, but it doesn't have the native plugin?

Or maybe it can be done within Craft core? I'm open to ideas.

*If you saw a Craft project with booking/reservations feel free to comment it here*

Comment: I think people use external services over self hosted booking systems, like channel managers. Some of them have APIs, so you could use a CMS (mmmh Craft) to showcase your booking subjects and booking forms.

Comment: Since most companies have their booking system and create a website for their company - instead of a booking system for their website - it's not really useful to handle reservations and bookings via CMS. So I doubt someone already did a plugin for that special use case. Imagine Pixel and Tonic drops Craft - the hotel had to change their entire concept only because the CMS isn't supported anymore.

Comment: @RobinSchambach My use case is rather something as simple as booking a spa visit or reserving a table in the restaurant.

Comment: I am exploring an appointment booking system to be used with Craft CMS. It would need to take bookings across multiple locations. Any recommendations of a third party solutions that could work with Craft via an API? Many th and

Answer (score 1):

Whilst one could build a booking system within Craft either with judicious use of Twig, Channels, and Entries or with a custom plugin it doesn't make a huge amount of sense to reinvent the wheel. Especially when booking management systems are deceptively complex when you get past the initial idea.

It would be possible to integrate pretty much any third party booking system into Craft with a bit of custom plugin development.

Comment: Doesn't even necessarily need custom plugin development; a lot of off-the-shelf solutions will give some JS you can drop into the template

Comment: I was speaking more about being able to manage bookings from the Craft CP. But yes, you're correct. On the front-end much is achieved with embedded widgets.